# Non-matches match jobs in my Careers e-mail

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I just got this e-mail today, but the job that matched should never have matched my criteria, as none of the tags I am looking for was present in the job advertisement.

[image: Screenshot of wrongly matched job]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report! You're receiving this job because it contains javascript and node.js keywords. If you'd like to receive matches based on tag matches instead, you can *edit the alert* by replacing "javascript node.js" with "[javascript] [node.js]" in the keyword field.

Comment: Ah, as an (very) infrequent user of the search functionality, this was not clear to me. Modified my search settings, thanks!

Comment: @StephanBijzitter yes, agree! We're currently in early design stages for updates to search - one of the primary goals is clearer UX for search features like this one. If you have ideas or further comments about this, please share - your thoughts would be appreciated.